# Integrating with Signal cryptographic protocol. The server side of libsignal

Tags: java, android, server, cryptography

Setting up the client side of the libsignal protocol is straightforward

https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-java

I'm stuck on the next step. The instructions say you have to send the prekey bundles to a server which leads to two questions:

1) What is the 'server'? Is it just a matter of writing some code to store the keys or is there a Signal server that you have to install?

2) Is it safe if the server is not privately owned?

Comment: do the `Server for message delivery` and `Usage` sections in https://swiftpack.co/package/christophhagen/LibSignalProtocolSwift help?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question, i believe the server holds the prekey bundle for users who would like to communicate with you. More information like how often would you need to change the bundle etc, is given in their documentation.

As to is it safe if the server is not owned, they have talked about server trust.

> 4.7. SERVER TRUST
>
> A malicious server could cause communication between Alice and Bob to fail (e.g. by refusing to deliver messages).
>
> If Alice and Bob authenticate each other as in Section 4.1, then the
>   only additional attack available to the server is to refuse to hand
>   out one-time prekeys, causing forward secrecy for SK to depend on the
>   signed prekey's lifetime (as analyzed in the previous section).
>
> This reduction in initial forward secrecy could also happen if one
>   party maliciously drains another party's one-time prekeys, so the
>   server should attempt to prevent this, e.g. with rate limits on
>   fetching prekey bundles.